# Insert a line break inside <p:commandButton />

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, line-breaks

Basically I am simply trying to add a `<br>` (or something equivalent) to the "value" attribute of a `<p:commandButton>` like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{aBean.text}" />  
<!-- #{aBean.text} returns for example "text1<br>text2" -->
```

Sadly, there is no possibility to set `escape="false"`. Trying to add a custom converter didn't work, either. I have, without success, also tried to do it like this:

```
<p:commandButton>  
     <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{aBean.text}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

In my opinion adding a simple line break should be easy enough, right? Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `&#10;` which represents the XML entity reference for `\n`.

```
<p:commandButton value="text1&#10;text2" style="white-space: pre;" />
```

The `white-space: pre;` is mandatory on `<p:commandButton>`, but not on `<h:commandButton>`, because the PrimeFaces one generates it as a `<button type="submit"><span>` instead of a `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Hi BalusC, the [style="white-space: pre;"] was indeed what I was missing. Thanks for the quick answer!