# h:outputText with line break from resource bundle (properties files)

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to break the text that is displayed inside the value attribute of the `<h:outputText` , that works fine if i place the text directly inside the value attribute of the `<h:outputText` , but if I place the same text inside the property file , it stop working

here is an example of the text

```
A&lt;br /&gt;B&lt;br /&gt;C
```

this works fine:

```
<h:outputText value="A&lt;br /&gt;B&lt;br /&gt;C" escape="false"/>
```

does not work:

`<h:outputText value="#{text.someText}" escape="false"/>`

code from property file:

```
someText = A&lt;br /&gt;B&lt;br /&gt;C
```

the only way i found is wrap the `<h:outputText` with a `<pre>` tag , but that's not good enough cause it changes the font of the text , it look weird , and any way I hope that there is a JSF way to achieve the line breaks when working with a property file

b.t.w I looked at the following links , but they are no good for me

[JSF h:outputText line break for long words within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556980/jsf-houtputtext-line-break-for-long-words-within-strings)

[Insert a line break inside p:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270293/insert-a-line-break-inside-pcommandbutton)

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The properties files doesn't need to contain XML-escaped HTML. Properties files are not parsed by a XML parser like Facelets files. Just put the HTML plain in the properties file.

```
someText = A<br />B<br />C
```

Then you can use `<h:outputText value="#{text.someText}" escape="false" />` the usual way.

Comment: Thanks, that's weird I could swear that I already tried that one... Works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<:outputText escape="false" ... />` with the properties, if you want to use the formatting.

Comment: Already tried that one... I wrote in my Question... b.t.w i tried with false and true too...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a *similar* Issue: Also using a longer text from a property file, containing `<br />` was not rendered with

```
<h:outputText value="#{text.someText}" escape="false" />
```

while in some other cases it worked...

The String looked like this:

```
This is a longer string, <br />that should be wrapped.
```

As it turns out: The problem was **not** the `<br />`, but the unescaped `,` - ofc. that generated a List for the property value and not the expected Text.
Just in case anybody facing something like this.